# Add Dictionary to a list python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am new to python and I'm trying to create a csv parsing script.
I pass rows from the csv to a list but what currently troubles me is that I need to add the first header line as a dictionary in each item.

```
def parse_csv(datafile):     
    data = []
    with open(datafile, "r") as f: 
        next(f) #skip headerline
        for line in f:
            splitLine = line.strip(',') 
            rowL = splitLine.rstrip('\n') #remove the newline char
            data.append(rowL)
        pprint(data)

    return data
```

If the 1st header line has the dictionaries (e.g Title, Name etc) how am I going to pass to each stripped element?

e.g {'Dict1': 'data1', 'Dict2': 'data2' }

This may be considered duplicate but tried various ways from similar posts but none worked properly on my case.

Comment: Do you mean `line.split(',')`? Can you be more precise, I can't understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use the provided csv library. It will save you a lot of time and effort. Here is what you want to do:

```
import csv
data = []
with open(datafile, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
        print(row['Title'], row['Name'])
```

In this example each row is actually a python dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

@GeorgiDimitrov is certainly right that the proper approach is to use the `csv` module from the standard library, but, if you're doing this only for self-instruction purposes, then...:

```
def parse_csv(datafile):     
    data = []
    with open(datafile, "r") as f: 
        headers = next(f).split(',')
        for line in f:
            splitLine = line.split(',') 
            dd = dict(zip(headers,splitLine))
            data.append(dd
    pprint(data)

return data
```

This will **not** properly deal with quoted/escaped commas, &c -- all subtleties that are **definitely** best left to the `csv` module:-).